# memory issue inside my touchesBegan methodh

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, memory-leaks

I have a memory issue inside my project. But I don't know how to solve it. This is what I'm doing. Like you can see below I have a map with cities on it. When you tap on a city, the city lights up.

This is what I do in my touchesBegan method.

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        NSLog(@"Touched");
        CGPoint c = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: self];
        struct CGPath *pat = (__bridge struct CGPath *)([arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0]);
        struct CGPath *pat2 = (__bridge struct CGPath *)([arrayPaths objectAtIndex:1]);
        // repeat this line 42 time (creating a struct for every city)

       CGPathRef  strokedPath = CGPathCreateCopy(pat);
       CGPathRef  strokedPath2 = CGPathCreateCopy(pat2);
       //I also repeated this line 42 times

       BOOL pointIsNearPath = CGPathContainsPoint(strokedPath, NULL, c, NO);
       BOOL pointIsNearPath2 = CGPathContainsPoint(strokedPath2, NULL, c, NO);
       //I also repeated this line 42 times

       CFRelease(strokedPath);
       CFRelease(strokedPath2);
       //I also repeated this line 42 times



if (pointIsNearPath){
         if([self.subviews containsObject:_imgLommel]) {
             NSLog(@"Remove");
             [_imgLommel removeFromSuperview];
             [arrCities removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
         }else{
             NSLog(@"add");
           [self addSubview:_imgLommel];
             [arrCities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
         }
    }
    if (pointIsNearPath2){
        if([self.subviews containsObject:_imgHechtel]) {
            NSLog(@"Remove");
            [_imgHechtel removeFromSuperview];
            [arrCities removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"add");
            [self addSubview:_imgHechtel];
            [arrCities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        }
    }
     //What I do here is I place an image with the colored city on top off the other images. If the image is already there I remove it.

//I also repeated this line 42 times
```

So now the problem. Every thing goes good. But after selecting several images, the app shuts down and I get no error messages. I'm struggling with this problem for weeks know.

Can please somebody help me with this ?

Kind regards.

[image]

**EDIT**

After some testing I found out that I don't get the errors when I comment out the following lines:

```
if (pointIsNearPath43){
        if([self.subviews containsObject:_imgHoeselt]) {
            NSLog(@"Remove");
          //  [_imgHoeselt removeFromSuperview];
            [arrCities removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:43]];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"add");
          //  [self addSubview:_imgHoeselt];
            [arrCities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:43]];
        }
    }

//Commented it also out in the other cities.
```

Answer (score 1):

enable NSZombieEnabled to check memory issue inside project.

[image]

1. Go to Edit Scheme --> Arguments
   then

[image]

2- select the "Diagnostics" tab and click "Enable Zombie Objects"

This turns released objects into NSZombie instances that print console warnings when used again. This is a debugging aid that increases memory use (no object is really released) but improves error reporting.

A typical case is when you over-release an object and you don't know which one: