# app crashes when trying to add too many subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory, uiview

This is a question that follows on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177836/memory-issue-inside-my-touchesbegan-methodh).
What I'm trying to do is, I have a map with some cities on it. When you tap on a city. The city changes of color. (see image below).

So first I did the following. When I tap a city I executed this part of code.

```
 if (pointIsNearPath28){
        if([self.subviews containsObject:_imgNiuewerkerken]) {
            NSLog(@"Remove");
            [_imgNiuewerkerken removeFromSuperview];
            [arrCities removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:28]];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"add");
            [self addSubview:_imgNiuewerkerken];
            [arrCities addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:28]];
        }
    }
```

This went good till a certain point. If i had for example selected 20 cities and I selected one more. It crashes.

So I thought that it has a memory leak somewhere but it doesn't.

What I've tried next is to add all the imageViews at the same time to my view in my `DrawRect`. But then it also crashes.

So I think that that is going to be the problem. That I want to add to much images as `subviews`

[image]

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of your crash.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't get any error messages..

Comment: Enable the zombie and check?

Comment: Yes also check, no success

Comment: What does the debugger view in XCode say when the app quits?

Comment: Why are each of these "cities" (or whatever they) subviews?  Why not layers?

Comment: Stupid question:  Rather than switching views in and out why not just use the `highlithtedImage` parm on UIImageView initWithImage and toggle the view's highlighted state?

Comment: Look at the Device Logs to see if it contains a crash report (open Organizer -> Devices, select Device Logs under your test device).

Comment: 20 subviews is "not a lot" and certainly within "normal" limits. Your problem is not the *number* of subviews, it's something else.

Comment: 20 subviews is far from the limit (whatever it is).

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint set?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes I've set a exception breakpoint. But it does not catch anything. Sometimes it prints in my console "Received memory warning" But I've checked with instruments but don't have any clue

Comment: @trojanfoe what do you mean with layers ?

Comment: Using `CALayer` rather than `UIView`.

Comment: Smells like a memory warning not properly handled

Comment: @trojanfoe I've changed everything to a CALayer but still it crashes after selecting some cities.

Comment: How large are your city images files?